# Can not construct instance of javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar from String value

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm trying to take an XML String and deserialize it into an object. I keep getting this exception though:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar from String value '22:32:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '22:32:00': Unparseable date: "22:32:00")
```

When it gets to this line:

```
xmlMapper.readValue(xml, clazz);
```

My XML contains:

```
<MyXML>
    <Event>
           <Time>22:32:00</Time>
    </Event
</MyXML>
```

My object class member variable is:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Time", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "time")
@JsonProperty("Time")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT+0100")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar time;
```

Is there anything wrong with this configuration that would cause the above exception?

Comment: Any luck I am facing same problem

Comment: I think what I ended up doing is specifying a custom getter & setter with `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonSetter`. The setter receives a `String` and parses it using the respective format. The getter returns a `String` in the respective format.